# UICollectionView transition between layouts with different datasources

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I've been wrestling with transitions between layouts, view controllers, collection views, and their animations for a while now. My goal for now is just to copy some functionality of the iOS Photos app: transitioning from a view with many stacks to a view with just those things in 1 stack.

So I set up a collection view with 4 stacks. You can transition to the LineLayout by tapping or pinching them open. The tricky part for me right now is the transition between a CollectionViewController with one data source (that informs it of all 4 sections) to one with another data source (that only shows it one section).

Here's the transition code, in a helper method:

```
- (UICollectionViewController *)nextViewControllerForIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    LineLayout *layout = [[LineLayout alloc] init];

    APLGridCollectionViewController *nextCollectionViewController =
    [[APLGridCollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout];
    nextCollectionViewController.collectionView = self.collectionView;
    nextCollectionViewController.collectionView.dataSource = nextCollectionViewController;
    nextCollectionViewController.selectedSection = indexPath.section;

    nextCollectionViewController.useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions = YES;

    nextCollectionViewController.title = @"Line Layout";

    return nextCollectionViewController;
}
```

If I don't set the nextCollectionViewController's collectionView to self's, the dataSource stays set to the current CollectionViewController, and it displays all 4 sections, and their cells, in the next screen.

The problem with this current implementation is that I get the following exception:

```
2014-06-25 13:37:00.774 CollectionViewTransition[743:142104] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData numberOfItemsBeforeSection:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3232.3/UICollectionViewData.m:556
2014-06-25 13:37:00.775 CollectionViewTransition[743:142104] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for number of items before section 3 when there are only 1 sections in the collection view'
```

...implying it's using the old data somewhere. So, what's the correct way to do this?

Admittedly, there are several other problems I'm trying to deal with, like the fact that going back to the stack layout screen animates everything into one stack, and some EXC_BAD_ACCESS thing too, but I'm not going to ask 7 questions at once.

[Here's the project.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ghxve61gjfhmge8/CollectionViewTransition.zip) It's WWDC sample code that I've modified, just as an initial attempt to get something working.

Comment: Not really, no. I ended up scrapping this and taking a different approach without view controller transitions, and keeping the same data source.